# how can i customize holo theme or make my own theme?

Tags: java, android, themes

How can I change the default blue to custom red in android studio?
This is Holo theme its default color is blue but i want red color

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in styles.

[image]

Change the attribute to your needs.

I believe what you're looking to change is the accent color.

```
<item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
```

Change the value to red (in colors.xml) and you're good to go.

Comment: where to add in style.xml??

Comment: wheelView.setSkin(WheelView.Skin.Holo);

Comment: this how i use in java

Comment: Are you using a library?

Comment: First try what I said in my answer.

Comment: If that doesn't work, find the view whose color you want to change, it will be something like
`style.selectedTextColor = Color.GREEN;
        myWheelView.setStyle(style);`

Try something like style.backgroundColor = Color.RED

Comment: it donot support of selecttextcolor